# Work in DEBUG mode but fail in RELEASE mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why does program work in debug mode, but fail in release mode?

Thanks...

Comment: You need to provide some error messages / code / information.  People here may be very talented but they aren't mind readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably using uninitialised memory somewhere.  In DEBUG mode memory is initialised to special values.  Make sure you're initialising all your variables.