# Project runs in debug mode but not in release mode

Tags: php, sockets

This code works in debug mode but not in relase mode I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868972/project-fails-in-debug-mode-but-works-in-release-mode)  and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547751/work-in-debug-mode-but-fail-in-release-mode) but I couldnt found a solution

```
  function domainSorgula($domainName, $ext)
{
    $server = trim($this->servers[$ext]);

    $output = "";

    try {
        if ($conn = fsockopen($server, 43)) {
            fputs($conn, strtolower($domainName) . '.' . $ext . "\r\n");
            while (!feof($conn)) {
                $output .= fgets($conn, 128);
            }
            fclose($conn);
            if (stristr($output, "No match") ||
                stristr($output, "No Data") ||
                stristr($output, "No entries") ||
                stristr($output, "No entries") ||
                stristr($output, "NOT FOUND")) {

                $this->durum[$ext]["durum"] = "bos";


            } else {
                $this->durum[$ext]["durum"] = "dolu";
                //  $this->durum[$ext]["son"] =substr($output)

            }


            $bas = strpos($output, "Expiry Date:");
            $t = substr($output, $bas, 23);
            $tarih = str_replace("Expiry Date:", "", $t);

            $this->durum[$ext]["son"] = $tarih;

                    echo '<pre>';
                    echo print_r($output);
                    echo '</pre>';

        } else {

        }

    } catch (exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

I get this error  "Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to whois.nic.tr:43 "

What am I doing wrong Any help would be appriciated

Comment: What do you mean by "debug mode"? To me, that code looks syntactically wrong, as you are missing a lot of closing brackets

Comment: Are debug and release running on the same machine? Could it be that the machine where you're running the release version is blocking outgoing connections?

Comment: Anyway, the two questions you linked have no relevance whatsoever with php, no need to refer to them.

Comment: I  editted my question.I mean It  gives me the right output while dubugging but not in release mod In release mod I get  "Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connec" exception

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca  I am testing in local server on the same machine

Comment: Does `$server` contain the same value in both debug and release modes?

Comment: yes I use this way   $this->domainSorgula("google","web.tr");

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how `$this->domainSorgula("google","web.tr")` relates to the code (and error message) in your question. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @ Federico klez Culloca  Sorry my bad plase take a look again I have editted my code

Comment: Ok, but `$server = trim($this->servers[$ext]);` has nothing to do with that, so again, can you please confirm that `$this->servers[$ext]` and therefore `$server` are the same for release and debug? Because if they are, I'm out of ideas.